# Request confirmation on lower confidence levels in Watson Conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I know how to set conditions based on intent match and confidence level.  I would like to proceed with a flow if the confidence is above a certain threshold, and request confirmation if it is in a mid-range before proceeding with the flow.

I can do this by doubling the nodes:

1. Create one node that matches at high confidence
2. Create a node underneath that matches at a lower level.  If I get confirmation, route back to first node, bypassing the condition.

Is there a better pattern that doesn't duplicate all nodes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused by your question, but, I believe you want make condition base on intent and confidence from intent. Right?

Well, I believe you can do this with code... And let Watson work only for the intelligence of the understandings of intentions and point the confidence. Or you can create a single node throughout the conversation as:

`if intent.confidence >= 0.75`

Response: I did not understand your question.

Or, with code for each set condition and intent, like:

```
if(intent[0].intents === 'requestPizza' && intent.confidence >= 0.75) {

data.output.text[0] = "Hey, you want request pizza or you want to know how to request pizza?";

}
```

See one [example](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/app.js#L77) from IBM Developers with Nodejs.