# Watson generic word from utterance

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Trying to create a set of entities & intents for things of the ilk "describe <something>" or "tell me about <something>" or "list instances of <something>".  The <something>s are not known in advance.  Consequently, I cannot exhaustively list the possible values for the entity.

My impression from (albeit very little) use and from the documentation is that the conversation API isn't good at this type of thing.  Experience thus far says that it will recognize things that match the examples given for some entity, but I haven't seen that it can generalize to something like

- describe @target
- show me instances of @target

without knowing the set of values for @target.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which services are you talking about?  NLC is able to do this, and so is Conversation, by using wildcards.  Either one of these can be trained to recognize intents with wildcard values in their training data.  Just use an asterisk ( like this - "*" ) for the wildcard.

You don't have to train Conversation with every possible utterance, it learns from it's training data.  So if you provided the service a series of utterances like "describe apples", "describe oranges", "describe fireflies", and "describe astrophysics", and then associated all of them with an intent of "#provide_description", then the Conversation service would indicte this intent for requests like "describe math".

Please also try to use real utterances for your training.  I am not sure that your users will speak in two word sentences all of the time.  Provide enough training data for each intent so the service is able to learn the various different ways people express the same intents.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try to find the information about the wildcards.  With respect to training data, there are lots of different phraseologies in the training data.  I simply didn't include it all in the question.

Comment: I didn't find any real description of this.  When putting in examples such as "tell me about \*", the intent trains fine.  It recognizes the intent.  However, the entity for \* doesn't get returned.  

I would like to define an entity "target" and have the API determine the entity value.  That is, "tell me about squirrels" should return the intent (which works fine) and return "squirrels" as the target entity.  This latter part does not work.  Putting in \* as a value for the entity (with or without Fuzzy Matching enabled only recognizes the value "\*" as the entity.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example, you can combine the Intents and Entities for your purpose.

It's a good practice, I think.

Like Daniel said, you can create one intent with examples for asking about something, like these examples within your #describeAbout:

- Describe about
- Can you please describe
- Can you please explain about
- List instances of

etc...

**And create one entity like @typesDescribe, with yours values. Like this values:**

- Paper
- Love
- Fruits

**After Watson training your examples, with your Dialog, create one flow with the condition**

```
if #describeAbout AND @typesDescribe:Paper
```

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

- `@typesDescribe` (Will show the value: Paper) is a thin material produced by pressing together moist fibres of cellulose pulp derived from wood, rags or grasses, and drying them into flexible sheets.

And, usually, if your confidence about Intent and Entity are small, you can add one more condition for your Intent with the confidence level that you want. [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44071242/7133482).

Obs.: You can create one Intent alone, with condition `#describeAbout`, and the response will ask for your user "You can know what?", and create one flow with various `@typesDescribe:value`, for example.